# Flutter IOS app won't start with image_picker: ^0.6.3+4

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios

The **Flutter** app is not starting when I try to use **Image_Picker** on the **IOS** side. On the Android side everything works fine.

I have added following permissions inside **info.plist**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <!-- for Image Picker -->  
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <String>This app requires access to the photo library</String>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires access to the camera</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app does not require access to the microphone</string>
    
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
```

When I remove the above properties form **info.plist**, the app works fine until I use the camera. But if I add the properties into **info.plist** the app won't start.

**I am getting following error when I am trying to run the IOS app.**

> /Users/abcshah/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-btwtkgmqdpzzlbcimpfmyibbmiua/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/**assetcatalog_generated_info.plist**
>
> **error**: unable to read property list from file: /Volumes/abc/projects/new/iconspro/ios/Runner/Info.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (**XCBUtil**.**PropertyListConversionError** error 1.) (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
>
> note: Using new build system
>
> note: Planning build
>
> note: Constructing build description
>
> Could not build the application for the simulator.
> Error launching application on iPhone 8 Plus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that my first guess was not completely off. I am using the image_picker plugin in my project as well and was able to produce a bunch of errors by changing the tag from **string**

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key> 
<string>This app requires access to the camera.</string>
```

to **String**

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key> 
<String>This app requires access to the camera.</String>
```

Therefore i recommend to pay attention to the casing of your tags. 
**Make sure all `<string>` tags are lower cased.**

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to build in legacy mode. Load your project in xcode and go to:

**File** -> **Workspace Settings** -> **Build System**, and change to **Legacy Build System**

Clean then rebuild and that should work for you

Comment: I will try and update the post. Thanks for your time.